# spark read.csv on Windows with multiLine=True produces strange unicode results

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Environment:
Windows 10, python 3.6.5, spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7 (local), pyspark 2.3.1

Consider the following script:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

fname = 'test.txt'
data = 'a,\xf3,b'
encoding = 'UTF-8'

with open(fname, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data.encode(encoding))

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
result = spark.read.csv(fname, sep=',', encoding=encoding, header=False, multiLine=True).collect()[0][1]

# Excpected:
result == '\xf3'
# Actual:
result == '\xc3\xb3'
```

Quite interesting, but `\xf3'.encode('utf8') == b'\xc3\xb3'`, that is, it seems that utf-8 bytes are re-encoded by treating them like unicode code points.

On the other hand, for (default) `multiLine=False`, the script produces the correct/expected result.

Further, this is reproducible also by writing a similar script in Scala. However, on Linux (tested on Fedora and Ubuntu) the script produces the expected result.

I know that there is a known issue (e.g., https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/448) that `encoding` is ignored with `multiLine=True`. However, my script uses utf8 encoding, which is the default encoding and should work.

My question is: Is this a known issue in Spark that I couldn't find reference for? Is it problem in my configuration/environment? In that case, are there some pointers where to start looking? Do you have any ideas for a workaround?